# Could not get pipeline: loadVisitor (domain: )

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

if anyone aware of this error please let me know:

Could not get pipeline: loadVisitor (domain: )

This error occurred when run the site on any browser[image]

Comment: Can you check if `Sitecore.Analytics.config` exists in `App_Config/Include` directory? Have you done any changes recently which caused that it stopped working?

Comment: Thanx Maras! Error solved!

Comment: I appreciate your help. May I have your skype id, That would be helpful for me for future

Comment: Hi Maras, I would like your skype id as well. It would be so much easier for me, than contacting Sitecore Support ;)

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer. Glad it helped. If you guys have any problems, you can always contact with me be email marek.musielak()gmail

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error happens when `CorePipeline` tries to run a pipeline and cannot find the configuration for it.

`LoadVisitor` pipeline is a **Sitecore DMS** pipeline and configuration for it is stored in `Sitecore.Analytics.config` file.

Most probably `Sitecore.Analytics.config` is missing in your `App_Config/Include` directory.

Comment: Hi Marek, I have faced with the similar issue. I've got following error message: `Could not get pipeline: listManagement.getLockedLists (domain: )`. This message repeats every minute in log file. Can't figure out how to fix this issue. Could you get me some advice, please?

Comment: Yuri, the exception message looks similar, but it looks like your case is completely different. You should create a new question with all the details like stacktrace, Sitecore version and installed modules.

Comment: Just in case, link to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35577530/sitecore-issue-could-not-get-pipeline-listmanagement-getlockedlists-domain . It's already solved.

Comment: @Marek Musielak I have a similar case. See this https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22061/how-can-i-solve-could-not-get-pipeline-speak-client-getstyle-domain. Maybe you can help me :)