# Sitecore issue: Could not get pipeline: listManagement.getLockedLists (domain: )

Tags: sitecore

I have found following error message in log file:

> ManagedPoolThread #16 11:21:54 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent
>   ManagedPoolThread #16 11:21:54 ERROR Exception
>   Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   Source: mscorlib

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Message: Could not get pipeline: listManagement.getLockedLists (domain: )
>
> Source: Sitecore.Kernel
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
>      at Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.PipelineBasedContactListStore`2.GetLockedListIds()
>      at Sitecore.ListManagement.ListManager`2.GetLockedLists()
>      at Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent.Execute()

It is written in the log file every minute. Can't figure out how to fix this issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what version of sitecore are you using? did you make any updates?

Comment: Yea, I agree with @SitecoreClimber. This is most likely a mismatch between your config files and the Sitecore binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listManagement.getLockedLists` pipeline is defined in `App_Config\Include\ListManagement\Sitecore.ListManagement.config` file.

You should check if this file exists in your local Sitecore instance.

If not, check clean Sitecore instance which uses same version and copy this file from there.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but this file exists there

Comment: Does it contain the definition of the missing pipeline? Check also `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` if you can find the definition there.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have replaced this config file by one from clear Sitecore 8.1 version, and now it looks like there is no error message more in log file. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problems appear when you make an upgrade of Sitecore version or when you start a new project and copy dlls from other version of Sitecore.

For example you start a new Sitecore project 8.1, and you install in Inetpub a clean version of 8.1. But on source of the project you have dll from older version of sitecore (Sitecore 8.0 for example).

When are you doing a new build you copy old dlls to inetpub but the config files are from Sitecore 8.1. And in this way is a mismatch between dll-s and config files.

Comment: Yes, I have upgraded Sitecore version from 8.0 to 8.1. Do you have any suggestions how to check, what dlls exactly can be wrong?

Comment: Download a clean 8.1 installation and copy the sitecore binaries from the bin folder to your project, would be my approach.

Comment: Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.dll check the version of this file Sitecore.ListManagement.ContentSearch.dll

Comment: It's 1.1.0.5289. I've found the same version of this dll on a clear version of Sitecore 8.1

Comment: Maybe in this file are using other dlls. Copy all dlls from a clean  Sitecore 8.1

Comment: Ok, will try to do it. Thank you for help